# how to make shape with diagonal div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, diagonal

I want to make this shape :
[image]
there supposed to be 3 div shapes like this. I built already some shape, but I want to see how this shape will fit in my website

I already built this : 
[codepan](http://codepen.io/Ariel7342/pen/EPxLQe)

css example for what i did :

```
.mainOuterDiv{

    height:300px;

    overflow:hidden;
    background:#FFF;
}
.middDiv{
    width:70%;
    height:75px;
    background-color: #0CF;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:50%;
}
.innerLeft{
    position: absolute;
    left: -60px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: skew(180deg,215deg);
    background-color: #0CF;
}
.innerRight{
    position: absolute;
    right: -60px;
    top: -20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: skew(180deg,145deg);
    background-color: #0CF;
}
.textDiv{
    z-index:9999;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #0CF;
}
```

is there a way to make this in css ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make diagonal div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104128/how-to-make-diagonal-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some example :

```css
.container
{
  position:relative;
  width:400px; height:302px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.mainDiv
{
  height:300px; width:300px;
  background-color:white;
  border:solid 1px black;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;right:0;margin:auto;
}
.middDiv
{
  height:55px; width:70%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
  margin:auto;
  z-index:10;
}
.leftDiv, .rightDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:26px;
  width:30%;height:48px;
  background-color:blue;
  z-index:10;
}
.leftDiv 
{
  left:-13%;
  transform:rotate(30deg) skew(30deg);
}
.rightDiv
{
  right:-13%;
  transform:rotate(-30deg) skew(-30deg);
}
.leftBDiv, .rightBDiv
{
  position:absolute;
  width:13%; height:47px;
  bottom:59px;
  background-color:black;
  z-index:9;
}
.leftBDiv
{
  left:-12%;
  transform:rotate(-30deg) skew(-30deg);
}
.rightBDiv
{
  right:-12%;
  transform:rotate(30deg) skew(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="middDiv"></div>
    <div class="leftDiv"></div>  
    <div class="rightDiv"></div>
    <div class="leftBDiv"></div>
    <div class="rightBDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I use different colors for middle, left and right blocks so You can see it.

If You will use border for those `divs`, You have to change `positions`: `left`, `right` and `bottom` for all of them.

There is **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khbxL162/)** example, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the responsive version with `skewY` i have used `:pseudo` elements

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.content {
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}
.shadow {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 18%;
  bottom: 18%;
  background: #7092BE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}
.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  background: #7092BE;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: -28%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.shadow:before {
  left: -30%;
  transform: skewY(-23deg);
}
.shadow:after {
  right: -30%;
  transform: skewY(23deg);
}
.ribbon {
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 18%;
  bottom: -1px;
  background: #7092BE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
.ribbon:before,
.ribbon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  background: #7092BE;
  height: 100%;
  top: -28%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.ribbon:before {
  left: -30%;
  transform: skewY(23deg);
}
.ribbon:after {
  right: -30%;
  transform: skewY(-23deg);
}
hr {
  margin: 20px;
  0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Nullam dictum felis eu pede
  </div>

  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
  <div class="content">
    Nullam dictum felis eu pede
  </div>

  <div class="shadow"></div>
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
</div>
```